# Shell's `RANDOM` is not determined by seed when used with `awk`

Tags: bash, shell, random, awk

Consider the following shell script, and the output that follows...

```
#!/bin/bash

RANDOM=5

for i in {0..9..1}
do
        rand_val=$(awk -v rand_awk=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{print rand_awk;}')
        echo "generated $RANDOM"
        echo "generated in awk: $rand_val"
done
```

First run:

```
generated 18499
generated in awk: 9147
generated 9909
generated in awk: 20212
generated 24640
generated in awk: 24874
generated 15572
generated in awk: 2499
generated 5516
generated in awk: 10235
generated 17897
generated in awk: 8039
generated 19000
generated in awk: 26744
generated 12793
generated in awk: 2500
generated 27730
generated in awk: 20895
generated 5509
generated in awk: 887
```

Second run:

```
generated 18499
generated in awk: 16728
generated 9909
generated in awk: 31548
generated 24640
generated in awk: 11705
generated 15572
generated in awk: 10184
generated 5516
generated in awk: 6024
generated 17897
generated in awk: 838
generated 19000
generated in awk: 20789
generated 12793
generated in awk: 3646
generated 27730
generated in awk: 21647
generated 5509
generated in awk: 18333
```

Third run:

```
generated 18499
generated in awk: 6725
generated 9909
generated in awk: 9301
generated 24640
generated in awk: 24364
generated 15572
generated in awk: 19016
generated 5516
generated in awk: 21737
generated 17897
generated in awk: 9027
generated 19000
generated in awk: 17942
generated 12793
generated in awk: 19478
generated 27730
generated in awk: 9555
generated 5509
generated in awk: 31563
```

It looks like inside `awk` statement, the numbers generated by `RANDOM` are not affected by the seed (5).
I want `rand_val` to also be effected by the seed that `RANDOM` gets, mainly because I want to use `awk`'s `rand()` function in a predictable way:

```
#!/bin/bash

RANDOM=5
RANGE=3

for i in {0..9..1}
do
        rand_val=$(awk -v rand_awk=$RANDOM -v range=$RANGE 'BEGIN{srand(rand_awk); print rand()*range;}')
        echo "generated in awk: $rand_val"
done
```

Comment: what version of awk are you using? gnu awk 4.1.3 here does generate the same sequence each time, and srand() changes it reliably as well. And don't expect bash and awk to generate the SAME numbers, even if they have the same seed. They do NOT use the same random generator.

Comment: @MarcB How do I check my awk version?

Comment: like pretty much any other unix-based util. `awk -v`.

Comment: Tried it, but this shows the help:
`awk: option requires an argument - v`
...
...

Comment: `rand()` IS predictable, that's the "problem" with it and the reason `srand()` exists. Your first script isn't doing anything at all with awk except printing the `$RANDOM` value that was passed into it. Your output is misleading as it says `generated $RANDOM` and `generated in awk: $rand_val` but in fact what it's really showing is `$RANDOM the 2nd time it's used in the loop` and `$RANDOM the first time it's used in the loop`. If you changed `rand_val=$(awk...)` to `rand_val="$RANDOM"` you'd get the same output. There's a better way to do whatever you are trying to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's the fact that `$(...)` creates a subshell and `RANDOM` is a special variable.  A minor change gets your first script to respond consistently:

```
#!/bin/bash

RANDOM=5

for i in {0..9..1}
do
        R=$RANDOM
        rand_val=$(RANDOM=$R awk -v rand_awk=$R 'BEGIN{print rand_awk;}')
        echo "generated $RANDOM"
        echo "generated in awk: $rand_val"
done
```

I simply reassigned $RANDOM to another variable, and passed that in instead.

Comment: Great. That's what I was looking for...
Strange... Why does the subshell produce unpredictable sequences?

Comment: As I said, I think `RANDOM` is a special variable.  In this case, I think it's reset at the top of every shell invocation, probably for security purposes.  Overall, I think it makes a lot of sense, even though you're surprised by it here.

Comment: This is it. You can find it in [Bash Reference Manual → Bash Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables).